# Is it possible to add and modify the dns cached entry in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dns, xpcom

I am trying to accomplish some specific test requirement.

One of the requirement now is to redirect some nonexistent url to specific ip, which is what the dns is doing. I think firefox is using internal dns cache. But I cannot find a proper service that I can use to change such kind of dns cache. On the other hand, i have no idea if firefox support some kind of service to customize the dns process, I mean give a customized result instead of really getting from DNS Server.

As I need to start many firefox process to do the work concurrently, so I cannot do this simply by changing the system hosts file, cause it will affect other process.

Any idea?

Comment: Why would Firefox have its own DNS cache? Sounds to me like a waste of resources, doubling something the IP stack does for you anyway.

Comment: Oh, maybe I should not use word "cache". It is something like, if you refer to a host second time, it should not use DNS Server this time, it should use a internal saved result. Of course, such result has a expire limit.

Comment: you're describing DNS cache, so why not using "cache" for it? It's just that its not done in Firefox (or, so I believe), but in the OS IP stack. Exactly as you described. To override the DNS resolution you should indeed use the hosts file, and it will affect all the processes in the system (unless they perform their own resolution, as Firefox does not because changes to the hosts file affect it).

Comment: @littleadv: All browsers have a DNS cache. One reason would be [DNS rebinding attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, modifying DNS responses isn't possible in Firefox, the DNS service merely allows triggering a DNS request. What you *could* do is recognizing `NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST` response and somehow redirecting it to your server. While recognizing isn't particularly hard, redirecting is complicated. You could [add a progress listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners) and check whether a request finished in `onStateChange` method (`if (aFlag & STATE_STOP)`). The parameter `aStatus` gives you the status of the request, you would be looking for status `Components.results.NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST`. And for top-level requests (`aFlag & STATE_WINDOW`) you could change window location to make a request to a different server instead. For other requests - don't know how one would "redirect" there.